# Channel Fields Error After Updating to 2.7

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker, channel

I just updated to 2.7 and I was in the backend.. When I clicked on the name on one of the channel fields I got:

> Fatal error: Declaration of Safecracker_file_ft::display_field() must becompatible with that of EE_Fieldtype::display_field() in /home/site/public_html/dev/system/expressionengine/third_party/safecracker_file/ft.safecracker_file.php on line 5

This happens when I click any of the channel fields.. whats happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `safecracker_file` from your `third_party` directory. It has been deprecated (now rolled into the standard File fieldtype).